# Rails association loop display same primary key in row

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a loop using associations. I'm looking to group by treatment and display in a row.

Each loop has three records for each treatment. The code below this is what i'm producing.

[image]

**VIEW**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Treatment</td>
        <td>Date</td>
        <td>Count</td>
    </tr>
    <% @trial.establishmentMethods.order(:treatment_selection_id).each do |data| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= data.treatmentSelection.treatment.name %></td> This is reference by treatment_selection_id.
        <td><%= data.date %></td>
        <td><%= data.count %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

This is what i'm hoping to produce. Display the treatment once, then loop the related `treatment_selection_id's` on the same row.

[image]

Here are my models and associations.

```
class Trial < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :assessments, primary_key: 'trial_id'
  has_many :establishmentMethods, through: :assessments
end

class EstablishmentMethod < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :treatmentSelection, primary_key: 'treatment_selection_id', foreign_key: 'treatment_selection_id'
  has_many :treatments, through: :treatmentSelection
end

class TreatmentSelection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :treatment, primary_key: 'treatment_id'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `TreatmentSelection has_many establishmentMethods`, so you should add that to the TreatmentSelection model. Then you can do something like:

```
<% treatment_selections.each do |treatment_selection| %>
    <tr>
        <td><%= treatment_selection.treatment.name %></td>
        <% treatment_selection.establishmentMethods.each do |em| %>
            <td><%= em.date %></td>
            <td><%= em.count %></td>
        <% end %>
    </tr>
<% end %>
```

By the way, it's convention to use snake_case in ruby and it will make using associations easier.

Comment: Sadly I get the following error. undefined local variable or method `treatment_selections' for #<#<Class:0x007fa744f56ca0>:0x007fa74e3dd6a8>

Comment: Sorry, I was kind of doing pseudo code there. You need to get your `@treatment_selections` into your view like you did with `@trial`